# MySQL remote connection [not as usual]

Tags: mysql, linux, connection, firewall

I'm not getting to get access to mysql externally.
I think it's mysql or firewall stuff or some privilege within the mysql.

I already tried doing steps that are on internet. I'll put the process step-by-step to exemplify what I'm doing and to serve as a tutorial for another people that has this same problem:

I'm using:

```
-ubuntu server 12.04 
-mysql-server5.5
-there is NO hardware firewall just software one
```

**1- First I installed mysql with:**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

**2- I changed the root password by:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root mysql
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('MYPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

**3- I give ALL PRIVILEGES to root to any ip:**

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**4- After I edited the my.cnf**

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

I commented the lines, as bellow:

```
#skip-external-locking 
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

**5- I edited the iptables to allow MySql 3306:**

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

now typing netstat -ant:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 66.123.173.170:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 66.123.173.170:22       189.32.2.232:49167      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    336 66.123.173.170:22       189.32.2.232:49654      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
```

See that port 3306 is open! Am I right?

**6- I restarted the mysql:**

```
sudo service mysql start
```

I typed:

```
service mysql status
```

result:

```
mysql start/running, process 20757
```

**7- I tried to connect to the server:**

```
mysql -h 66.123.173.170 -u root -p
```

I got this error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '66.123.173.170' (111)

When I do:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

It works opened MySQL> terminal

**8- DOUBT: Do you see anything wrong with this process?**

OBS: on step 4, I also tried to put the bind address to 
bid-address = 0.0.0.0 
but it didn't solve the problem.

**9- DOUBT: If I turn off the MySQL with: `service mysql stop` then, can I access the firewall locally with mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p ?**

I did it and I could connect even with mysql stopped/waiting (this was the status given after stop and retrieveing status of MySQL).

Comment: try turning off the firewall to see if it works if not try uncommenting #bind-address and put your ip there to see if it works. This way you can pin point why its not working.

Comment: +1 for providing so much information in your question.  Good job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Resumed solution:**

I killed the mysqld that was holding the 3306 port and restarted it.

I think this is a bug or something related check step-by-step what I did:

**1- Created a program to connect on 3306**

First I create a simple program in Java to make sure there wasn't any problem with my firewall. The program just open a port on 3306 with TCP connection by 2 minutes just for testing, the program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class PortMysqlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 3306;

        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try
        {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            ss.setReuseAddress(true);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 2;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (ss != null)
        {
            try
            {
                ss.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }       
    }
```

**2- Stopped the mysql service**

Before executing the program I stopped the mysql service:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

or it can be done with:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**3- Started My program with java PortMysqlTest**

My program (PortMysqlTest) throw an exception saying the address/port as already in use by mysqld!

Surprise? As far as I know the with mysql service stopped the port should be free. Am I right? (I'm not sure of it if someone can answer this...)

**4- I searched for the application PID that was using the address/port with:**

```
sudo netstat -lpn | grep 3306
```

the answer:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6736/mysqld
```

**5- I killed the process with:**

```
kill -9 6736
```

OBS, if you don't know what kill do:
6736 is the process that was holding the port, I got this number with step 4, 6736/mysqld

**6- Now I run my program again:**

java PortMysqlTest and connected with telnet (telnet 66.123.173.170 3306) externaly and ***it worked***!

So the problem *wasn't the firewall*, because I could connect externally to the machine 66.123.173.170.

**7- Started the mysql service again:**

(I waited 2 minutes for my program do stop and free the 3306 port) and started the mysql service again to test, with:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

**8- I did connected externally with telnet:**

```
telnet 66.123.173.170 3306
```

***and worked!!!***

After I tried connect to mysql with:

```
mysql -h 66.123.173.170 -u root -p
```

***and worked!!!***

**Conclusion:**
I think there was a bug with my MySql installation; 
or something, (I don't know what is), when restarting mysql the mysql doesn't get the configuration of:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

or

```
bind-address = *
```

I hope this help someone else.

Comment: Your hope has not been in vain, it helped me :)

Comment: Excellent. Worked perfectly. I've been trying for hours. Killing mysql was the key!

Comment: you are God! Thank you sir! spent last 3 hours trying to figure out the problem :(((

Answer (score 2):

Your netstat output shows that it is not open to external connections, it should show `0.0.0.0` in there instead of `127.0.0.1` (which is loopback, not local as such).

You probably need to add a different `bind-address` to your mysql config (and don't forget to restart the service).

Try

`bind-address = *`

or your actual NIC ip (`66.123.173.170`) perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to set your bind-address in my.cnf to 0.0.0.0 not just comment out the line.

As a side note, you should probably not allow root access from all IP addresses as you say you have configured it.  I would limit root to local machine only.

Comment: I also tried to put the bind address to 
bid-address = 0.0.0.0 but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: So are you trying to use the external IP of 66.123.173.170 to open MySQL from the local machine?

Comment: yes I'm on a external machine trying to connect to 66.123.173.170.

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL listen on localhost. You need to configure it to run on your actual interface or you can use 0.0.0.0 address in bind.